# convert hex to byte without conversion

Tags: c#, hex, arrays

I have a very specific requirement. I have some data. Of which, strings and spaces are to be converted to EBCDIC while numbers to Hexadecimal.
For Example, my string is "Test123"
Test => EBCDIC
123 => Hexadecimal.
What I am trying to do is check every character in string if its number or not, and then based on that doing my conversion.

```
byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[length];
        int i = 0;

        if (toEBCDIC)
        {
            foreach (char c in data)
            {
                byte[] temp = new byte[1];
                if (Char.IsNumber(c))
                {
                    string hexValue = Convert.ToInt32(c).ToString("X");
                    temp = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hexValue);                        
                    dataBuffer[i] = temp[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    temp = Encoding.GetEncoding("IBM01140").GetBytes(c.ToString());
                    dataBuffer[i] = temp[0];
                }

                i++; 
            }


            dataBuffer.CopyTo(array, byteIndex);
```

The problem comes when i try to convert the number. I need to keep my output in byte array, as i have to write the output to a memory stream and then to a file.
When i get the hex value of number, and then try to convert it to byte, actual conversion happens.
For "1", hexvalue = 31.
Now I want to keep this 31 unchanged in bytes. I mean to say that, when i write it to byte array, it should remain 31 only. But when do GetBytes, it makes byte array, converting 3 and 1 separately to bytes.
Can anyone please help me on this..!!

Comment: EBCDIC?! Even my parents aren't old enough to remember that.

Comment: Do you know the format of the digits? always 000 <256 or also ##0  or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
ToString("X")
```

Now it's a hexadecimal *string*. So in your example, from this point onward, the 3 and the 1 have become separated.

How to fix this: don't convert.

```
if (Char.IsNumber(c))
{
    dataBuffer[i] = (byte)c;
}
```

Not tested. I think that's what you want. At least, that's what you describe in the last paragraph. That wouldn't make the numbers hexadecimal though - it would make them ASCII, and it's a bit odd to be mixing that with EBCDIC.

Comment: This converts "1" to decimal, instead of hexadecimal. I need 31 as result of conversion, but this gives 49.

Comment: @Anshul no it doesn't. That's just how you're looking at it in the debugger. Switch to hexadecimal view to see 0x31. Both are just illusions, a `byte` is not intrinsically in any base.

Comment: Thanx. I was looking in debugger and getting confused. Checking in hexadecimal shows correct value. Thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

You convert the char to its code and then convert that code to string. You don't have to do the second step, instead use the code directly:

```
if (Char.IsNumber(c))
{
   byte hexValue = Convert.ToByte(c);                       
   dataBuffer[i] = hexValue;
}
```